# Neighbor Discovery?

Tags: osgi, bonjour, zeroconf, jmdns, mdns

Hello,                                                                                           In order to get a list of the surrounding nodes announcing services in an IP network, I was trying to use Bonjour from Apple. However, I couldn't get an "easy" tutorial to do so. Moreover, I've noticed that most of the websites focus on the dynamic IP address allocation, services, etc. But I couldn't find any info about detecting the other nodes in the network. Although it looks easy and clear, I don't know from where to start. Note: I need to use Java (osgi bundles).                                Need Help please!!
Thanks

Comment: ... and I couldn't make a free download of Bonjour for Windows... :(

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify, you can only discover other services:

- That are on your link-local network (possible to search other domains but it's rare)
- That are advertising themselves through mDNS

If you need to perform service discover through Java, I'd suggest using [JmDNS](http://jmdns.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Do you know if there is an OSGI version of JmDNS?

Comment: No but it shouldn't be difficult to write an OSGI bundle exposing the JmDNS methods. Is mDNS really what you're looking for? Define a 'node' in a network.

Comment: yes, I think JmDNS is sufficient according to what what I read about it.. Actually, I just need to discover the surrounding nodes in the local network and also the services that they can offer... but I need it to work on both Windows and Linux, it is based on Java prgramming (JVM) so I suppose it works well, I'mI wrong?

Comment: It'll work on Windows, Linux etc but jMDNS only picks up advertised mDNS services; it won't detect every node on the network if it's not advertising a service.

Comment: ok, thanks and this is exactly waht I need :)                            But now I'm facing some probelms creating an osgi bundle for my application, although I'm starting with a very basic and simlpe example :(